# Git rebase removing more recent changes?

Tags: git

I have a `master` branch and two working branches, `a` and `b`. Branch `b` was created from the same point as `a` but touches different files (only one shared, `d.py`). Branch `b` was just pulled into `master`.

```
                (a)   F---H-J----L---
                     /
(master)A--B--C--D--E--------------M
                     \            /
                 (b)  G----I----K
```

In my pull request for branch `a` Github now says

> This branch has conflicts that must be resolved
>
> Use the web editor or the `commandline` to resolve conflicts.
>
> Conflicting files
>
> clippy/d.py

I thought I could do the obvious, `git pull --rebase master` and end up with a history that looks like this:

```
                             F---H-J----L--
                            /            
A--B--C--D--E--------------M
             \            /
              G----I----K
```

And then merge into master and everything would be great

```
                             F---H-J----L
                            /            \
A--B--C--D--E--------------M--------------N
             \            /
              G----I----K
```

When I attempted the merge this is what I got

```
You are currently rebasing branch 'bug/1500/Things' on '1234567'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   apps/a.py
    modified:   apps/b.py
    modified:   apps/c.py

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    both modified:   apps/d.py
```

And I assumed that everything would be great. But then I took a look at `a.py` and realized all my changes from commits `F`, `H`, `G` and `L` had disappeared. Same for `b.py`, `c.py` etc. As far as I can tell, the only changes that stuck in the rebase were the ones in `d.py` which was the file shared between the two branches.
I aborted the rebase and tried again with just `git rebase master` but the same thing happened.

Why is git doing this? And how can I successfully rebase my commit to merge it?

Comment: Your missing commits should be in a stash. It tried to rebase but failed because of conflicts. A rebase will stash then re-apply the stash, if the re-apply failed then everything remains stashed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If there are conflicts between master and your `a` branch, the rebase will stop at the point where the conflict exists and expects you to fix it.

First off, to get to the original state of your branch, you can do `git rebase --abort`. This will undo the attempted rebase.

If you are still in the middle of the rebase, you can do `git diff` to see where the conflicts are. You'll see something like this in the conflict files

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
...
=======
....
>>>>>>> branch-a
```

You can edit the file to fix the conflicts by choosing the code that you want to keep and removing the `<<<<` `=====` `>>>>>>>` lines.

Once you've finished editing the files and conflicts, you can run `git add .` and then `git rebase --continue`. The rebase will continue moving your commits up to `HEAD`. At any point, you may or may not run into more conflicts. If you don't, you'll see that the rebase worked successfully and then you'll be able to push your changes to your branch. Since you've rebased, however, you'll only be able to do perform a forced push since your commit refs will have changed from the ones on the remote.

Answer (score 9):

Same thing happened to me. What's happening is you are still in the middle of a rebase and it's not done so your latest up to date modifications should still be ok if it was committed.

The rebase is going back from the beginning of all the commits in the past that you might have to catch up on (for instance, if your other developer made 10 commits from a few days ago that you need to integrate in your app). Or simply don't accept it or whatever fits best for your app.

Then hit the "+" to add it/include it onto your local branch. (No need to commit/push since you're just bringing it onto your local branch to work off of that).

Then:

```
git rebase --continue
```

Then go one by one through all the old commits that have conflicts with your newest commit until you get to your latest which should be reassuring once you see those recent modifications that look normal.